Data on webpage loads only when the webpage is in-view | Selenium | Python
I am trying to scrape jobs data from this URL: https://www.upwork.com/nx/find-work/most-recent
The webpage loads fine when I have the browser in view. Otherwise, Selenium can get only the first two jobs.
Notes:

Scrolling does not work
Waiting does not work
Wait Until does not work
Headless does not work

It can only load all jobs when the webpage is open and in view. Even if I open another program above the browser, the data would not load.
Looking for help :)
Below is my code snippet:
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy import Selector
from rich import print
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from time import sleep

EMAIL = ""
PASS = ""

def botInitialization():
    driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chromedriver_path))

    return driver


def login(driver):
    user = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login_username")
    user.send_keys(EMAIL)
    user.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    sleep(2)
    print("Email Entered...")

    password = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login_password")
    password.send_keys(PASS)
    print("Password Entered...")

    rememberme = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login_rememberme")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", rememberme)
    sleep(1)
    print("Remember Me Clicked...")

    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    sleep(10)
    print("Logged In...")

    return driver

    

driver = botInitialization()


print("Getting the MOST RECENT...")
driver.get("https://www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/login")
sleep(2)

driver = login(driver)

driver.get("https://www.upwork.com/nx/find-work/most-recent")
sleep(5)

response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)

jobCards = response.css("section[data-ev-feed_name='Most Recent']")

print("Jobs Found: " + str(len(jobCards)))

